# Autocomplete entry Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

возникла такая проблема.
Стандартными средствами не могу реализовать Autocomplete entry или ему подобное. Фреймворк очень дорого покупать, да из его функционала нужно только это.
Прошу Вашей помощи в данном вопросе, нужно что-то по типу такого, только для Xamarin.Forms
[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/auto-complete)

Comment: https://youtu.be/hAmcxAmbLcA или [это](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/autocomplete-textfield-with-suggestion-dropdown-in-xamairn-forms)

Comment: Можете еще здесь глянуть https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotMorten.Xamarin.Forms.AutoSuggestBox/